# Does closing an unqualified covered call option result in realization of gains on the underlying?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, covered-call, covered-call-writing

In general, in a covered call scenario, does any trade on the options contracts trigger a realization of capital gains on the underlying? I am not concerned about the reset of the holding period on the underlying.

Say, I have 100 AAPL stock with $1000 in unrealized gains, and I opened a short call option today. Then I closed the call option tomorrow for no gain no loss. Will this trigger a realized short-term gain on the underlying stock (i.e. a realized gain of $1000)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sell a covered call, there are 3 possibilities:

1. At a later time you buy the call back, closing your short call position.  This could result in a capital gain or a capital loss.
2. The call expires worthless.  This would be a capital gain.
3. You are assigned and you must sell your stock at the strike price.

The first two scenarios result in a short term capital gain (or loss) on the option transaction. You retain your stock along with your unrealized gain (or loss).

Only scenario (3) `triggers a realization of capital gains on the underlying.`

As an aside, short options receive STCG treatment even if they are held for more than a year.